# TreeView Confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, treeview, web-parts

basically I have list of, Groups, another List for Users in the group &&& Individual users list.
Now i want to make (non expandable) treenodes from the list of users, then another expandable node for groups (with list of users in them) but I am really bad with treeview, and tutorial not helping either :/
here's the code

```
            TreeView tree = new TreeView();
            List<string> GroupList = new List<string>();
            List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> UserList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            List<string> IndividualUserList = new List<string>();

            GroupList.Clear();
            UserList.Clear();
            IndividualUserList.Clear();

            foreach (string GroupListItem in GroupList)
            {
                TreeNode groupNode = new TreeNode();
                foreach (string Item in IndividualUserList)
                {
                    groupNode = new TreeNode(Item);
                }

                groupNode = new TreeNode(GroupListItem);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> UserPair in UserList)
                {
                    if (UserPair.Key == GroupListItem)
                    {
                        groupNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(UserPair.Value));
                    }
                }
                tree.Nodes.Add(groupNode);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly something like this should allow you to add the groups and users within those groups.

```
TreeView tree = new TreeView();

foreach(string groupName in Groups) 
{ 
    var groupNode = new TreeNode(groupName); 
    foreach(KeyValuePair user in UserList) 
    {
        if(user.Key == groupNode)
        {
            var userNode = new TreeNode(user);
            groupNode.Add(userNode);
        }
    }
    tree.Add(groupNode);
}
```